# Tried copying some files from a DVD and got Error Code -36. Nothing helped...any possibility of retrieving data?

Tags: mac, dvd

The exact error is:

The Finder can’t complete the operation because some data in “FileName” can’t be read or written. (Error code -36)

I can't do dot_clean cuz it's on a DVD. I tried cp -R, got Input/Output Error. Tried tar compress onto HD and the result is the same as clicking OK to the error message and get a blank file copied.

Would anyone be able to say whether this due to the DVD being partially damaged (because some files can still be opened) or is it the files that show this error are the problem? Is there any way to get them out of the DVD or open them completely the same as they were saved years ago (15 to be exact). Thank you very much!

Comment: note that a `-36` file system error means the file is damaged and can't be read. The answers below might help. Might.

Comment: Thank you. That seems the case, but then I read that people were able to correct it using dot_clean? But not an option for me as it's on a DVD... I thought there might be a way..

Answer (score 0):

15 years is a lot !! Some files might still open and some might not.

Your DVD must be having a lot of scratches so the only way you can read any data from the DVD is by cleaning the DVD surface.Try googling some of the ways to clean DVD's like toothpaste or buy a DVD repair kit from amazon.

Comment: And get a DVD lens cleaner as well.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I don't think its related to the lens because he said " some files can still be opened". Had it been the lens, I doubt any file would open.

Answer (score 0):

15 years for a DVD-R is quite a long time.

However, your DVD drive itself could be nearly that age [as Apple haven't made a Mac with an optical drive since 2010 or so], & they don't last forever either.

The first simple tests for optical disks is to

- Check they're not scratched.
- Check around the edges to make sure the layers are not delaminating
- Hold up to the light & check for bright dots or patches which would indicate the dye layer has started to rot.

SysTweak has a list of the usual suspects to look at for data recovery - [Best Free CD Recovery Software For Mac 2019](https://blogs.systweak.com/best-free-cd-recovery-software-for-mac/) which would all be worth a shot.

If the data is particularly valuable, you could first get a new external DVD drive, they're pretty cheap these days. If still no joy, then a professional recovery service might be able to help - but they are not cheap & provide no guarantees.

Comment: Thank you. I think it was burned maybe on a G4 or something which already got a DVD drive? I can't recall. It's actually dated 2005.. but the file was likely created in 2004. The DVD's been pretty well taken care of - mostly in a DVD book hardly accessed through the years (hence only found the issue now). I'll check it like you said though.